# Beamer two columns whole document

Tags: beamer, multicolumn

How can we set beamer document to two columns for the entire document without `columns` environment from frame to frame

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{.75\linewidth}
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.25\linewidth}
                black space for explanation!
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
    %
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{.75\linewidth}
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.25\linewidth}
                black space for explanation!
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, did my answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you ?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\newcommand{\mytwocolumnframe}[2]{
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.75\linewidth}
          #1
        \end{column}
          \begin{column}{.25\linewidth}
          #2
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}      
}

\begin{document}
\mytwocolumnframe{
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
}{
  black space for explanation!
}
\end{document}
```